# Permutations / Combinations of College Bowl outcomes

Tags: loops, combinations, permutation

I am looking for help in identifying the permutations/combinations of the outcomes with spreads (win, lose, push) of the 40 bowl games.  Does anyone know how to figure this out, plus the programming algorithm to 'print' the combinations.  I know this must be a pretty complicated algorithm, but if there is a statistic guru out there, your help would be greatly appreciated.

How many combinations are there?  Plus do you know the looping involved in identifying each combination?

Thanks.